# Custom UITableViewCell with wrong backgroundColor

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` based on a Storyboard Prototype cell. In my custom cell class I color the cell based on the cell state "selected" or "highlighted" the code looks something like this:

```
- (void)updateCellDisplay {
    if (self.selected || self.highlighted) {
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor myLightBlueColor];
    } else {
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    [self updateCellDisplay];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self updateCellDisplay];
}
```

Now I have this weird behavior with iOS7 that after a selection is over, the cell redraws itself completely blue. The label is not visible any more. It looks like the cell got a foreground color that covers everything. This works fine on all iOS versions prior to iOS7.

[image]

[image]

[image]

what could that be?

Comment: I found out that it has something to do with the selectedBackgroundView of the custom UITableViewCell. The blue color you see is the selectedBackgroundView applied like this 
`UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:drawerCell.frame];
            selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor customLightBlueColor];
            drawerCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;` It covers all other views inside the content view of the UITableViewCell. This only happens with iOS7. I think it's a bug. Anyone know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the contentView of the cell is above the content. I had a similar problem and solved it by adding my custom items in the contentView in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

In my case, the items didn't receive touches, for the contentView was over.

`[[cell contentView] addSubview:cell.itemTitleView]`

I hope it helps.